# How to have the ITEM and SUBITEM in the list view

Tags: android, listview

with Android Studio I have this ListView in the MainActivity

```
ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter;
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myRssFeed.getList());

                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and this shows me the title of the feed I return from RSSItem.
Is there a way to have the description, images, ecc. for SUBITEM and the title I return for ITEM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Expendable list which will allow you to show group and kind of sub-group. To do so you need to create a BaseExpandableListAdapter. You need to override two methods of this class.

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
               }
        //TextView tv=new TextView(context);
         TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGroupName);
        //tv.setText(parentList[groupPosition]);
         tv.setText(category_list.get(groupPosition).toString());
        //tv.setPadding(70,0,0,10);
        //return tv;
         return convertView;

    }

@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
               }
        //TextView tv=new TextView(context);
         TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerName);

        //tv.setText(childList[groupPosition][childPosition]);
         tv.setText((String)((ArrayList)sub_category_list.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition));

        //tv.setPadding(70,0,0,10);
        //return tv;
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there a way to have a simple listview with item and subitem?

Comment: No. you need to go for custom only.

Comment: Are you sure only custom? I was on Google Play on my device and I could see a simple ListView with many Items.

Comment: No, ok I understand how to do.